# Lock A Built-in Application?

Tags: permissions, osx, sudo, chmod

I know I am able to lock an application using:

```
sudo chmod a-x /Applications/'Application'.app
```

but I encountered a problem
while trying to lock an application, like safari, which is built in.

```
chmod: Unable to change file on /Applications/Safari.app: Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way to override the permissions?

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: It said chmod: Unable to change file on /Applications/Safari.app: Operation not permitted

Comment: And yes I am admin

Comment: This is [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204899); you can't get around it without disabling the whole thing; you probably want the parental controls instead.

Comment: Is there a way to enable specific parental controls from terminal and disable parental controls from terminal?

Comment: I don't know. I suspect you'd get a better answer to that on [apple.se]. I would guess there must still be some way as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being unable to change permissions as root on a built-in application or system file on OS X is indicative of [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204899), a new security feature added in 10.11, which

> restricts the root account and limits the actions that the root user can perform on protected parts of OS X.

Protected parts include `/System` and pre-installed applications, along with the traditional Unix tree.

Any item under a path listed in `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf`, or with the `com.apple.rootless` extended attribute listed by `xattr -l`, is unmodifiable except by the users listed in the first column of that file, unless SIP has been [disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) in recovery mode (which I would advise against, generally).

By nature, **this protection includes the root user**, and anyone with admin or `sudo` rights. Only Apple-signed binaries can modify these files.

You can also see [this popular reporting article on Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/) from when the feature was introduced for more details, including some more about how it works and what the purpose is.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to achieve your desired results as the root user on Mac OS X prior to 10.11 "El Capitan".

> "The user account named "root" is a special user in UNIX-style
>   operating systems that has read and write privileges to all areas of
>   the file system."

If you have not already enabled the root user, here are the instructions on how to enable and use the "root" user in OS X.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

On the CLI:
1. Type `su` to switch to the root user.
2. Then `chmod a-x /Applications/Safari.app` will work

Comment: This just isn't correct, as noted in the comments on the question.

Comment: It indeed works, I've tested it. The comment on the question indicates he used sudo as admin. The root user has higher privileges than a sudoer or "admin" user.

Comment: `The root user has higher privileges than a sudoer or "admin" user`. No it doesn't.

Comment: Michael, Why don't you try it and report back. IT WORKS!

Comment: And — just to make sure — I just tried it too, and it definitely doesn't work. The error reported in the question is indicative of SIP, the entire point of which is that even root can't get around it.

Comment: See screen shot. https://www.evernote.com/l/AJIU6gD3LOBBPZghOalC9KC9h0dEoHVA3n0

Comment: For that to be meaningful you'd need a screenshot showing that error when using `sudo`, followed by success when using `su`; all you've shown there is something that isn't relevant to the scenario posed in the question. You don't have SIP enabled.

Comment: Updated answer. The OP did not specify his OS. This answer will work on Mac OS X prior to 10.11 "OS X El Capitan".

Comment: The entire scenario can't occur in an earlier version.